# How does one package a python application that includes a gsettings schema with setuptools?

Tags: python, packaging

I'm trying to use `setuptools` to package a python application that relies on gsettings for storing and retrieving user's preferences. However I have not used said tool before and I am unsure about what to do with the `setup.py` script in order to instruct it to install and compile the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add your schema to `setup.py`

   ```
   setup(...,
         data_files=[('/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas', ['filename.schema.xml'])]
        )
   ```
2. Add a system call in `setup.py` to run:

   ```
   glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   ```

As ntc2 commented bellow that this will fail when custom installation path is use, example with `--user`.

- One possible solution is to use relative path `share/glib-2.0/schemas`, That also would imply reconstructing input folder path for `glib-compile-schemas` command using  `sys.prefix` variable.

Comment: This will fail for `--user` installs.

Comment: @ntc2 one possible solution is to use relative path `share/glib-2.0/schemas`, That also would imply reconstructing input folder path for `glib-compile-schemas` command using  `sys.prefix` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `glib-copmile-schemas` in a custom `install_data` subclass in `setup.py`. For example, this is how we do it in [fluxgui's `setup.py`](https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui/blob/9cf8101caf56e6474acd08e9b3319cb0452d0b3e/setup.py):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.log import info
import distutils.command.install_data, os.path

# On Ubuntu 18.04 both '/usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas' (global
# install) and '~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas' (local '--user'
# install) are on the default search path for glib schemas. The global
# search paths are in '$XDG_DATA_DIRS'.
gschema_dir_suffix = 'share/glib-2.0/schemas'

data_files = [<other data files>,
    (gschema_dir_suffix, ['apps.fluxgui.gschema.xml'])]

class install_data(distutils.command.install_data.install_data):
    def run(self):
        # Python 3 'super' call.
        super().run()

        # Compile '*.gschema.xml' to update or create 'gschemas.compiled'.
        info("compiling gsettings schemas")
        # Use 'self.install_dir' to build the path, so that it works
        # for both global and local '--user' installs.
        gschema_dir = os.path.join(self.install_dir, gschema_dir_suffix)
        self.spawn(["glib-compile-schemas", gschema_dir])

setup(<other setup args>,
    cmdclass = {'install_data': install_data})
```